# Laravel and Composer installation on Linux Mint

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

I have a Linux Mint machine I am working on. I want Laravel to install on it.

When I search for this I got this command: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` from "https://getcomposer.org/download/" to put in terminal but it gives me this:

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After i have done sudo apt-get install curl

```
libcurl3 curl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main curl i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

got this which is not successfully installed curl

How can any one I successfully install these things and Composer and Laravel?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli` first. You'll likely want a web server too, in which case do `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 apache2` as well.

Comment: I have tried this @halfer but got same error.

Comment: Ah, what version of Mint are you running? Maybe it is no longer supported? Did you try `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: its I have two linux macine one is server other one is client
Server version is -> Linux Mint 14 (nadia)
Client version is -> Linux Mint 15 (olivia)
I have a big issue regarding this 
Please help out of this if you can @halfer

Comment: Are those versions still supported? Please check on the Mint website.

Answer (score 0):

The Composer already hints you the way to install those, you should run those commands, enter your password en those libraries should be installed automatically, after you install those libraries rerun the composer download.

Comment: I have used that but not exactly download all dependencies .because i am using linux mint.can you tell me anything else to install laravel @Sjors

Comment: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu which has the APT-GET functionality. What errors do you face while executing these commands?

Comment: Did you try sudo apt-get update ? Some dependecies returned 404, which means the URL's registered in APT-GET doesn't exist anymore, they've may been updated.

Comment: Maybe, you should install it then.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have the latest version of curl installed.

I made a bash file for the whole process of global installation of Laravel and Composer.

1. [Download it from here](https://gist.github.com/arvinismaili/73283bc73536e79fc6f47ec16708eab5)
2. Open a terminal in the bash file directory
3. Run the command below:

   ```
   bash Laravel_Global_Installer.sh
   ```

This bash file manages installations of:

- Latest version of PHP and its extensions
- Latest version of Composer (Global)
- Latest version of Laravel (Global)